# Google maps Pushpin Error

Tags: android

I want to show the particular location on the map and on that perticular location i want to put the pushpin notification. I have tried the below code but it showing nullpointer exception please help me to add the markers.

```
public class MapDemoActivity extends MapActivity {
 MapView mapView; 
 MapController mc;
 GeoPoint p;
 class MapOverlay extends com.google.android.maps.Overlay
    {
        @Override
        public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, 
        boolean shadow, long when) 
        {
            super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);                   

            //---translate the GeoPoint to screen pixels---
            Point screenPts = new Point();
            mapView.getProjection().toPixels(p, screenPts);

            //---add the marker---
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                getResources(), R.drawable.pushpin);            
            canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, screenPts.x, screenPts.y-50, null);         
            return true;
        }
    } 

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);

        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mc.animateTo(p);
        mc.setZoom(17); 

        //---Add a location marker---
        MapOverlay mapOverlay = new MapOverlay();
        List<Overlay> listOfOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
        listOfOverlays.clear();
        listOfOverlays.add(mapOverlay);        

        mapView.invalidate();

    }
@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
```

Comment: add your logcat and see line no. where nullpointerException occur....

Comment: 03-09 11:28:10.430: E/AndroidRuntime(487): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-09 11:28:10.430: E/AndroidRuntime(487):  at com.MapDemo.MapDemoActivity.onCreate(MapDemoActivity.java:78)
03-09 11:28:10.430: E/AndroidRuntime(487):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-09 11:28:10.430: E/AndroidRuntime(487):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
03-09 11:28:10.430: E/AndroidRuntime(487):  ... 11 more

Comment: see line no.78 in your MapDemoActivity.java:78

Comment: I have seen that i dont undrstand that how to get lat lon points of the touched events so that i can pass

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `GoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);` described in [Markers of Google Maps Android API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/marker)

then you can use `setOnMarkerClickListener` of `MapView` class like this:

```
mapView.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener() {
    @Override boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
        // marker clicked
    }
});
```